# Pulling amend commit from repository

Tags: git

For example, User A and B checkout same develop branch, and A user uses **--amend** to merge his X commits and push it to repository **--force**, then B user will get conflict when pulling it from repository.

In that case, I(=User B) usually Stash my working files and delete the local branch and checkout the remote branch again and apply the stashed files.

But I am just wondered is there any other clean way to pull the updates from remote? rather than deleting local working branch and checkout again?

Comment: Instead of deleting the local working branch, you could try a rebase. Documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Comment: How can I rebase with remote branch? I have done rebase with the other local branchs, but I've never done rebase local develop branch with remote develop branch.

Comment: Do a fetch to 'fetch' the remote changes and then do a manual merge by cherry picking or a rebase ... A pull is a bad idea because it tries to merge as well...

Comment: After a force push, the pusher is responsible to tell every team member the fact that he/she has made a force push, and kindly ask them to fetch the latest force-pushed branch(es) and re-apply the missing commits to the branch(es) if there are any.